# Multi level pointer as argument c++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, arguments

I will use a pseudo example here, though I have noticed this behaviour in several APIs, like sqlite3 or windows.

Say a function is declared like so:

```
    void Fu(some_identifier **ppBar);
```

and I do this in my code:

```
    some_identifier **ppFubar;
    fu(ppFubar);
```

It is my understanding that this would work and indeed it does in my own functions. Yet my program crashes after a buffer overflow when I do this with some APIs.

If I do this:

```
    some_identifier *pFubar;
    fu(&pFubar);
```

everything is fine.

Do ppFubar and &pFubar not evaluate to the exact same thing?

EDIT:

A concrete example would be (fourth argument):

```
int sqlite3_prepare(
  sqlite3 *db,            /* Database handle */
  const char *zSql,       /* SQL statement, UTF-8 encoded */
  int nByte,              /* Maximum length of zSql in bytes. */
  sqlite3_stmt **ppStmt,  /* OUT: Statement handle */
  const char **pzTail     /* OUT: Pointer to unused portion of zSql */
);
```

Comment: "some APIs" may well require you to have allocated something and pass it.

Comment: Maybe the problem is somewhere else, for instance in the scope of the dereferenced pointer on in what it points to.

Comment: Only if you initialize ppFubar to point to some `*some_identifier`. If not, it's just an uninitialized dangling pointer.

Comment: They have the same result type, but that's all they have in common

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is wrong.

If a function takes a `some_identifier **ppFubar;` parameter it is probably going to do something related to a `some_identifier` object somewhere inside its function body.

If you call it with `some_identifier **ppFubar;` you are giving it an uninitialized pointer, i.e. a pointer to garbage. If the function does anything with it (for example, it dereferences it, either once or twice), you are incurring in undefined behaviour (most likely, it will crash).

Pass a correctly initialized pointer to the function.

Comment: I edited my question to add an example API. For this function I would need to initialize `ppStmt` to a `*sqlite3_stmt` ? I would assume the API would make `ppStmt` a valid pointer, no?

Comment: @user2731962 You need documentation on what needs to be passed to the function. Without it, you cannot use it. The function you posted as an example is very badly documented, because it doesn't tell you exactly what you need to send to it. This is one of the reasons why having API's taking double pointers is a bad idea.